# How to add search results in my website to cart page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am facing this problem creating a cart page for my website, i have a search engine that displays records and i want to create a add to cart system for it before choosing the payment type..Am new to this ,so any help offered is deeply appreciated.

```
<?php
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search'];

if (!$button)
    echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else {
    if (strlen($search) <= 1)
        echo "Search term too short";
    else {
        echo "You searched for <b> $search </b> <hr size='1' > </ br > ";
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", 'register');
        $search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);
        $x = 0;
        foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
            $x++;
            $construct = "";
            if ($x == 1)

                $construct .= "keyword LIKE '%$search_each%' OR  job_type  LIKE '%$search_each%' OR  profession  LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
            else
                $construct .= "AND keyword LIKE '%$search_each%' OR  job_type  LIKE '%$search_each%' OR  profession  LIKE '%$search_each%' ";

        }
        $construct = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE $construct ";
        $run = $conn->query($construct);
        $foundnum = $run->num_rows;
        if ($foundnum == 0)
            echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b> $search </b>. </br> </br> 1. Try more keywords. for example: If you want to search 'For a person in the Banking Department' then use general keyword like 'Banking','Business','Finance' or if the person needed resides in the Information  technology Department, then use general keyword like 'I.T' ,'Information, technology','Informatics' etc. <br> </br> 2. Try different words with similar  meaning </br><br> 3. Please check your spelling";
        else {
            echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";
            $per_page = 10;
            $start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : '';
            $max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
            if (!$start)
                $start = 0;
            $getquery = $conn->query("$construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            while ($runrows = $getquery->fetch_object()):

                echo "<h5>CV<b>{$runrows->id}</b></h5><br>";
                echo "<b>Gender</b>: {$runrows->gender}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>About</b> : {$runrows->about}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>Nationality</b>: {$runrows->nationality}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>Marital status</b>: {$runrows->marital_status}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>Languages spoken</b>: {$runrows->lang_spoken}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>Job Wanted</b> :{$runrows->job_type}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>Profession</b> :{$runrows->profession}<br><br>";
                echo "<b>Qualifications </b>: {$runrows->qualifications1}<br><br>";
                echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm more-info' data-id='{$runrows->id}'>View & Request Cv</button> ";
                echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm more-info' data-id='{$runrows->id}'>Add to cart</button>";
```

Also Attached is an image of the search results.

[screenshot of the search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLaox.png)

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Any errors or what? Please, be concrete

Comment: None please, seeking direction on how to implement the add to cart page from the search results, probably sending the result of that particular id to the cart page

Comment: I have no errors on my search page, seeking help to create a cart page where i can use the add to cart button to send in my search results

Answer (score 1):

You could add to cart with an anchor tag

```
echo "<a href='?id=$runrows->id'>Add to cart</a>";
```

This will add id parameter to the cart page which you can retrieve with $_GET

Comment: My problen is am clueless as to how to start the cart page